# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0. Only on certain build

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

I'm working on porting a discord.net bot I made to a raspberry Pi, and I'm getting an error when I build and run it on the pi that does not show up when I build and run it anywhere else.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

This is the error I get when running the project (token data for the bot is stored in json files) they are read from completely fine when I run the project out of visual studio on my PC, but when I build the project on the PI and run it I get this error.

I found a stackoverflow page on this error and none of the solutions seem to be solving my issue.

- I ran my json data through a validation website and it checks out
- I saw one post talking about it maybe being a UTF encoding issue, so I tried a fix where I'm passing in UTF-8 encoded text, and same error. Then I tried with UTF-32 and that makes the error appear on my PC and on the PI!
- I have a feeling that it has something to do with its encoding, but I really am stuck here and I cannot find anymore forums discussing this issue. Any pointers or ideas are appreciated!

This is the code that is throwing the error, `JsonFromPath` returns raw json data from a file, `DataFromJson` is what deserializes it, and this is where the error is being thrown.

```
public string JsonFromPath(string path)
{
    try
    {
        string result;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { return ex.ToString(); }
}

public T DataFromJson(string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
}
```

Comment: You need to include the json in your question.

Comment: It seems likely to me that your `JsonFromPath` method is encountering an error and returning the exception rather than the JSON. There doesn't seem to be much sense in catching the read error if you're not going to handle it in a way that allows your application to continue to behave in a predictable way. It would be better to just let it bubble up.

Answer (score 2):

```
public T DataFromPath(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                string rawJson;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    rawJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rawJson);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return default(T);
            }
        }
```

I changed the code to this and for some reason it works now smh