# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value ASP.NET Core and Newtonsoft

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net, streamreader, memorystream

I am trying to parse a JSON file into an object using Newtonsoft in my ASP.NET Core application but I keep getting this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'palette.swatch', line 7, position 15.'

I've tried using the `StreamReader` class and now `MemoryStream` class. I've confirmed validated the JSON online and checked it is UTF-8 too. Both ways I receive the same error. I also manually checked the JSON but I can't see anything that would make it unreadable.

Here's the method that is throwing the exception:

```
public async Task<int> PostDefinition(IFormFile file)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    file.CopyTo(ms);
    byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
    string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

    Definition definition = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Definition>(s);
    Definition x = ObjectMapper.Map<Definition>(Definition);

    return await _definitions.InsertAndGetIdAsync(x);
}
```

This is the segment of the JSON that is throwing an error:

```
{
  "name": "Definition",
  "id": 2,
  "palette": {
    "name": "Test Palette",
    "default": false,
    "swatch": {
      "colors": {
        "Color 1": "transparent",
        "Color 2": "transparent",
        "Color 3": "transparent",
        "Color 4": "transparent",
        "Color 5": "transparent",
        "Color 6": "transparent",
        "Color 7": "transparent",
        "Color 8": "transparent"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What could be causing the exception and what can I try to remedy it? I've tried searching and nothing I try seems to work.

Comment: How did you define `Definition`? What does that class look like?

Comment: You can also try throwing an exception to make the code work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712500/newtonsoft-json-jsonreaderexception-unexpected-character-encountered-while-pars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me

```
 Definition definition = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Definition>(s);
```

classes

```
public partial class Definition
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("palette")]
        public Palette Palette { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Palette
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("default")]
        public bool Default { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("swatch")]
        public Swatch Swatch { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Swatch
    {
        [JsonProperty("colors")]
        public Dictionary<string,string> Colors { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, it was related to my class and mapping rather than the JSON. Instead it is working using a DTO which matched the JSON structure better.