# Post input from http request needs to be passed as a variable to AZ module

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-functions

I have a powershell based http trigger azure function that uses the Az module to call get-azvm. It get's it's data from a logic-app POST. The output looks correct and it's type shows as string but the cmdlet does not like the variable. The function looks like this:

```
Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."
$sub = $Request.Body.subject | Out-String
write-host "sub:" $sub
$split = $sub -split "[/]"
write-host "split:" $split
$avd = $split[8] | Out-string
Write-Host "avd" $avd

$rgName_avd = 'rg-azgroup'

Get-AzVM -Name $avd -ResourceGroupName $rgName_avd
```

The post input looks like:

```
/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/rg-azgroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myvmname-0
```

The error in the logs starts as:

```
[Error] ERROR: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.Exception             :Type       : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderExceptionTargetSite :Name          : ParseValueDeclaringType : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReaderMemberType
```

It feels like it's an issue with the input type but using ConvertFrom-Json does not seem to work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? If I hard code the VM name or define a variable locally and use it the command executes.

The AZ module versions being used in requirements.psd1:

```
@{
    'Az.Accounts' = '2.7.6'
    'Az.Compute' = '4.26.0'
}
```

Comment: Can I ask, on which line do you get the error? On `$sub = $Request.Body.subject | Out-String`, or on `Get-AzVM -Name $avd -ResourceGroupName $rgName_avd` ?

Comment: The error occurs at: Get-AzVM -Name $avd -ResourceGroupName $rgName_avd (also worth noting that the same script works without error if an event grid subscription is used for the same input)

Comment: In that case, I strongly suspect that something is going wrong with the way you're isolating the $avd value; if you add more detailed logging, you'll probably be able to figure out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few workarounds that you can try:

**Solution 1:**
You might not be passing JSON to  `DeserializeObject`.
It looks like that type of  `tmpfile` from  `File.WriteAllText(tmpfile,...`  is  `string`  that contain file path.  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`  takes JSON value rather than the file path, it fails trying to convert something like  `@"c:\temp\fooo"`  - which is not JSON.

**Solution 2:**
Check that is the file containing JSON string has [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
Once u remove BOM the problem may get resolved.

**Solution 3:**
For a Web API action that was binding to a  `string`  instead to an  `object`  or a  `JObject` when JSON was correct, but the binder tried to obtain a string from the JSON structure and failed.
So, instead of:

```cs
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public object Search([FromBody] string data)
```

Try this:

```cs
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public object Search([FromBody] JObject data)
```

References:
[Unexpected character encountered while parsing value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259173/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value)
[Unexpected character encountered while parsing value ASP.NET Core and Newtonsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119903/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value-asp-net-core-and-newtonsoft)